# How to get the Schema name of a Table in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, schema, entity

I use a User-Schema Separation technology to separate tables in the Database. Could you tell me how to get Schema names of EntitySets (Tables) in Entity Framework? Thanks.

Comment: @M.Babcock schema stands for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095.aspx

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, Our client separates tables into different schemas. There is a Audit Trail function which logs every change of tables. I want to add a column to identity which schema the table belonged to and can filter the Audit Trail record when SELECT.

Answer (score 4):

This must be an old topic by now, but for those still lurking with EF6+ (as in not EF core), based on the very same excellent blog [post](https://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/) of Rowan Miller from back in the days, check my approach for surfacing some meta information about a given entity

```
public class DbTableMeta
{
    public string Schema { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys { get; set; }
}


public static DbTableMeta Meta(this DbContext context, Type type)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    // Get the part of the model that contains info about the actual CLR types
    var items = (ObjectItemCollection) metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace);

    // Get the entity type from the model that maps to the CLR type
    var entityType = metadata
        .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
        .Single(p => items.GetClrType(p) == type);

    // Get the entity set that uses this entity type
    var entitySet = metadata
        .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
        .Single()
        .EntitySets
        .Single(p => p.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name);

    // Find the mapping between conceptual and storage model for this entity set
    var mapping = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
        .Single()
        .EntitySetMappings
        .Single(p => p.EntitySet == entitySet);

    // Find the storage entity set (table) that the entity is mapped
    var table = mapping
        .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
        .Fragments.Single()
        .StoreEntitySet;

    return new DbTableMeta
    {
        Schema = (string) table.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value ?? table.Schema,
        Name = (string) table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? table.Name,
        Keys = entityType.KeyMembers.Select(p => p.Name),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods for **DbContext** and **ObjectContext**:

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;

        return objectContext.GetTableName<T>();
    }

    public static string GetTableName<T>(this ObjectContext context) where T : class
    {
        string sql = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString();
        Regex regex = new Regex("FROM (?<table>.*) AS");
        Match match = regex.Match(sql);

        string table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
        return table;
    }
}
```

Using a ObjectContext object:

```
ObjectContext context = ....;
string table = context.GetTableName<Foo>();
```

Using a DbContext object:

```
DbContext context = ....;
string table = context.GetTableName<Foo>();
```

More info here:

[Entity Framework: Get mapped table name from an entity](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/entity-framework-get-mapped-table-name-from-an-entity/)

Comment: I am not going to downvote you, but using LINQ to SQL and regex seems like an awful way to get a table name.

Comment: @RuudLenders keep in mind that my answer is 6 years old! I haven't used EF in a long time - I'm pretty sure that as of 2018 is easier to access the metadata, but back in 2012 things were very different :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following blog entry that explains how to get at that information from the metadataworkspace:

https://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/

Here's the function that does the magic:

```
public static string GetTableName(Type type, DbContext context)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    // Get the part of the model that contains info about the actual CLR types
    var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

    // Get the entity type from the model that maps to the CLR type
    var entityType = metadata
            .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
            .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type);

    // Get the entity set that uses this entity type
    var entitySet = metadata
        .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
        .Single()
        .EntitySets
        .Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name);

    // Find the mapping between conceptual and storage model for this entity set
    var mapping = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
            .Single()
            .EntitySetMappings
            .Single(s => s.EntitySet == entitySet);

    // Find the storage entity set (table) that the entity is mapped
    var table = mapping
        .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
        .Fragments.Single()
        .StoreEntitySet;

    // Return the table name from the storage entity set
    return (string)table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? table.Name;
}
```

Comment: Dan Dohotaru posted this answer a year earlier, yet this got more upvotes?

Comment: @RuudLenders Hmm, that is indeed weird. Did I really just post almost the same answer a year later? Strange.

Comment: Dan posted nearly a year later, not a year earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For those using code-first, the schema name is set in the `OnModelCreating` override of your context;

```
public static readonly string DefaultSchemaName = "Entities";

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(DefaultSchemaName);

    ...
```

So you should be able to reference `DefaultSchemaName` from elsewhere in your code.

This answer is slightly less obvious if you didn't build the model context and EF stuff out in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Sample used for truncating tables where both table name and schema are required.

```
public void ClearTable<T>() where  T: class
    {
        var dbContext = (DbContext) _dbContext;
        
        var annotations = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetAnnotations().ToList();

        var tableName = annotations.First(c => c.Name == "Relational:TableName").Value.ToString();
        var schema = annotations.First(c => c.Name == "Relational:Schema").Value.ToString();

        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"truncate table {schema}.{tableName}");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Approved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285560/11104908) answer is true when Type is `Model.{Entity}` or **type.BaseType** be `Object` but if Type be `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies` you will get exception

> Sequence contains no matching element

for fix this issue just modify entityType like this

```
var entityType = metadata
                    .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                    .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type || objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type.BaseType);
```

Answer (score -3):

Using Entity Framework 6.1.3 you can query the scheme and the tablename in the following way:

```
  string tableNameWithScheme = context.Db<T>().Schema+"."+context.Db<T>().TableName;
```

Where T is the type of your Entity and context an instance of your derived System.Data.Entity.DBContext.

Comment: Are you sure? I think `Db<T>` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes i am completely sure in the case of using MSSql! Ahh and of course T is a parameter of your function!

Comment: So where is the Db<T> function [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)?  There's no such thing.